# Como devo utilizar o recurso de Autenticação do Visual Studio para um projeto ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio

Senhores, necessito de uma orientação para dar início a um projeto de desenvolvimento em ASP.NET MVC no Visual Studio. É relacionado à implementação do recurso de Autenticação ao se criar um novo projeto ASP.NET. Meu sistema possuirá dois tipos de usuários, os quais precisarão estar logados ao sistema para utilizá-lo. Vi que o recurso disponível de autenticação é muito bom e eficiente, pois já vem prontinho. Mas ele tem um porém, e está relacionado às tabelas criadas por ele em um banco de dados. Eu não consegui integrá-las às tabelas do meu sistema.

Diante disso eu gostaria de perguntar a vocês o que me recomendariam fazer e porquê:

- Utilizar o recurso de autenticação disponível e adaptá-lo ao novo
  sistema em construção (tive dificuldades em fazer isto), ou
- Não utilizar o recurso de autenticação e criar os mecanismos de login
  e sessão manualmente (dá mais trabalho e eu perco a oportunidade de
  utilizar um bom código gerado pelo Visual Studio, mas aparentemente
  tenho maior controle sobre seu funcionamento).

Preciso muito tomar esta decisão, por isso, desde já agradeço pela ajuda!

[image: Configuração do método de autenticação]